# android marshmallow: how to know if user deny one app permissions?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

on Android, I check if the location is enabled with

```
LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(GPS_PROVIDER) || LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

This work fine, however on marshmallow (and upper) when a user go in the app settings and deny only for my app the permissions to use the location (just for my app, like mashmallow now permit to do) then the previous request still return `true`

I try also :

```
MyActivity.checkSelfPermission('android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION') == PERMISSION_GRANTED or MyActivity.checkSelfPermission('android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION') == PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

But it's always return true even when the user deny the permission to my app

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion` set to?

Comment: to 14 (and i can't increase it right now) but normally it's must not matter no ? because checkSelfPermission was only introduced on api 23 so their is no raison to make it behave differently if targetSdkVersion < 23 ... i think !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are have `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` set to 23 in your *build.gradle*. If it is below 23, the app will use the old permission approach and the methods you mentioned will not work.

Comment: thanks kelevandos, but why this can't work with targetSdkVersion < 23 ? increasing targetSdkVersion to 23 gave me some other problem i don't want to face right now :(

Comment: Backward compatibility, they did not want to break the old permission handling. They still kind of did, but well xD

Comment: why Backward compatibility ? because checkSelfPermission was introduced on api 23 so their is no need of Backward compatibility ?

Comment: But you still want apps that were developed before 23 to work when installed on 23+ :-) So the new approach kind of "wraps" the old, assuming that the permissions are always given :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Comment: yes sorry i copy past wrongly, i do == and not = but always return true :(

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [link](http://typicaljava.blogspot.in/2016/09/checking-multiple-run-time-permission.html). Make sure you have `compileSdkVersion` should be 23 and above.

Here i have created the code with checking multiple runtime permission with should show rational.

Comment: yes compileSdkVersion is 23 (else i will not be able to  access the checkSelfPermission i think)

Answer (score 0):

`checkSelfPermission` doesn't return a boolean. It returns an integer.

This is the correct way to check permissions:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // permission is not granted, request it
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

} else {    
    //permision granted
}
```

And this is the way for handle them

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

From documentation

> https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: yes it's like this i do : MyActivity.checkSelfPermission('android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION') == PERMISSION_GRANTED but it's return true even when user deny the permissions :(

Comment: Have you tryed call it from *ContextCompat* instead of *MyActivity*. Can you show us your code?